# Custom Post Type Archive with Dynamic Taxonomy Filtering

Tags: taxonomy, urls, custom-post-type-archives

I have been learning about WordPress's built-in function as described in the title.

What I have learned is that WordPress will automatically filter the content displayed by the taxonomies specified in the url, i.e., **mySite/CPT-Archive/?someTaxonomy=someValue** should only display content with some `Taxonomy=someValue`. However, when I manually type this into the url, my archive page displays nothing. I made sure that I was using a valid `taxonomy+value`, specifically, I typed `?status=current` because I KNOW there is content with that setting.

My next task is to figure out how to allow the user to choose the filter(s), but before I do that, I need to understand why my archive does not follow the built-in url filtering from WP, and how I can change that.

Thanks!

**Edit:** The `if (haveposts) while (haveposts)` loop is not executed at all when I specify a filter as described above

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I'm running an older version of WordPress, which is probably why this isn't working. I will update to the latest version (4.3.1) and see if that works